# What does the phrase "trying to snow" mean?

Tags: phrases

What does the phrase *trying to snow* mean? E.g.,

> Trying to snow the audience ...

I think it is more of a slang usage. I am looking for a meaning other than weather related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Merriam Webster it means trying to impress, deceive or persuade your audience.

[snow](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snow)